# How can I conditionally assign a color to text in jade

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, mongodb

I have an application using mongodb, node.js, express, jade templating, jquery. I have a collection of documents that each contain a status of either 'active' or 'expired'. I'd like to display 'active' documents' date in green and 'expired' documents' date in red.

```
.list
    if (applications.length === 0)
      | No applications.
    each application, index in applications
      .item
        div
          -if (application.Status = "active")
            -$( ".dateapplied" ).addClass("activeClass")
        div
        div.dateapplied
          div
                  -var day = application.Applied.getDate()
                  -var m = application.Applied.getMonth()
                  -var y = application.Applied.getFullYear()
                  -var prettydate = m + " / " + day + " / " + y
          div

          span.name=prettydate
          |&nbsp
        div.name
```

The line -$( ".dateapplied" ).addClass("activeClass")
renders:

500 TypeError: /Users/eddie/logicalpath/jobkeeper/views/applications.jade:20 18| div 19| -if (application.Status = "active") > 20| -$( ".dateapplied" ).addClass("activeClass") 21| div 22| div.dateapplied 23| div undefined is not a function

My CSS classes are:

.activeClass {
  color: green
}

.expired Class{
  color: red
}

My goal is to have the date display in red for expired and green for active. I'm trying to use css classes as opposed to inline css.Im not sure how to add the class to .dateapplied. Or, perhaps I'm thinking of this wrong. Any help appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.list
    if (applications.length === 0)
      | No applications.
    each application, index in applications
      .item
        div
        div.dateapplied(class=(application.Status == 'active')? 'activeClass':'expiredClass')
          div
                  -var day = application.Applied.getDate()
                  -var m = application.Applied.getMonth()
                  -var y = application.Applied.getFullYear()
                  -var prettydate = m + " / " + day + " / " + y
          div

          span.name=prettydate
          |&nbsp
        div.name
```

You can apply conditionals inside attributes, like this:

```
(class=(application.Status == 'active')? 'activeClass':'expiredClass')
```

Comment: Thank you @tpae Ternary to the rescue!